# Usar correctamente el GOTO en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estimadxs, tengan buen día, estoy tratando de usar GOTO en SQL para saltearme un UPDATE en caso de un dato NULL o en 0, para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_EliminarDatos_2023]
    @titulo INT, 
    @cuota INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @plan_origen NVARCHAR(10)--Código plan
    DECLARE @salida_tabla INT
    DECLARE @fecha_grabacion_nula SMALLDATETIME
    DECLARE @endoso INT

    SET @salida_tabla = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla WHERE Titulo = @titulo AND cuota = @cuota)
    SELECT @fecha_grabacion_nula = FECGRABAC, @endoso = Endoso FROM tabla WHERE Titulo = @titulo AND cuota = @cuota

    IF @fecha_grabacion_nula <> NULL 
        GOTO Salida
    IF @salida_tabla = 0 
        GOTO Salida
    IF @endoso = 0
        GOTO Salida
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP(1) @plan_origen = PlanOrigen 
            FROM tabla 
            WHERE Titulo = @titulo
            ORDER BY Id DESC

            SELECT @importe_comprobante = amcuoplan 
            FROM tabla 
            WHERE plan_origen = @plan_origen


            UPDATE tabla 
            SET plan_origen = @plan_origen
            WHERE TITULO = @titulo 
                AND cuota >= @cuota

            SELECT 'SI' AS SALIDA
        END

Salida:
    SELECT 'NO' AS RESPUESTA    
END
```

Pero, a la hora de ejectuarlo:

```
exec SP_EliminarDatos_2023 123456, 10
```

Si me actualiza los datos, ¿Qué esto haciendo mal?

Comment: `IF @fecha_grabacion_nula IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso correcto es no usarlo ya que es una práctica arcáica que se mantuvo de lo que se llamaba código espaguetti. En tu caso es más sencillo usar un solo `IF...ELSE...`. También es más eficiente usar `EXISTS` que contar las filas.

EDICIÓN:
Otro problema con tus condiciones es que no tomas en cuenta que los `NULL` no se comportan de la misma manera que otros valores. Al usar operadores lógicos tradicionales (=, >, <, <>, etc.) contra un `NULL` no obtendrás falso o verdadero sino `desconocido`. Para poder comparar si un valor es nulo o no, tenemos que usar `IS NULL` o `IS NOT NULL` .

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_EliminarDatos_2023]
    @titulo INT, 
    @cuota INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @plan_origen NVARCHAR(10)--Código plan
    DECLARE @salida_tabla INT
    DECLARE @fecha_grabacion_nula SMALLDATETIME
    DECLARE @endoso INT

    SET @salida_tabla = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Titulo = @titulo AND cuota = @cuota) 
                                THEN 1 
                                ELSE 0 END;

    SELECT @fecha_grabacion_nula = FECGRABAC, 
           @endoso = Endoso 
    FROM  tabla 
    WHERE Titulo = @titulo 
    AND   cuota = @cuota

    IF @fecha_grabacion_nula IS NOT NULL 
    OR @salida_tabla = 0 
    OR @endoso = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'NO' AS RESPUESTA;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP(1) @plan_origen = PlanOrigen 
        FROM tabla 
        WHERE Titulo = @titulo
        ORDER BY Id DESC

        SELECT @importe_comprobante = amcuoplan 
        FROM tabla 
        WHERE plan_origen = @plan_origen


        UPDATE tabla 
        SET plan_origen = @plan_origen
        WHERE TITULO = @titulo 
            AND cuota >= @cuota

        SELECT 'SI' AS SALIDA
    END
END
```

**2da Edición:**

El uso de `GOTO` ha sido criticado en muchos lenguajes desde hace décadas. De hecho, desde 1968 el [prof.dr Edsger W. Dijkstra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_Dijkstra) envió una carta criticando su uso y mencionando que la calidad de los programadores era inversamente proporcional a su uso de `GOTO`. Ese artículo fue renombrado como "[Instrucción Go-to considerada dañina](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF)" por [Niklaus Wirth](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklaus_Wirth). La instrucción sigue siendo un *code smell* para distintas organizaciones como [Sonar](https://rules.sonarsource.com/tsql/RSPEC-907/) y [ApexSQL](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-code-smells-rules/category-code/#APX1095). Incluso xkcd tiene [un cómic](https://xkcd.com/292/) acerca de eso.

Comment: " ya que es una práctica arcáica que se mantuvo de lo que se llamaba código espaguetti. ".. no estoy de acuerdo con esto. tu respuesta no tengo ni idea si funciona, pero esto no es ni cierto, ni tiene absolutamente nada que ver con codigo spagheti... podes tener codigo spagheti, como en js, sin absolutamente ni un goto...

Comment: Esto de todas formas es lo que no funciona `IF @fecha_grabacion_nula <> NULL`

Comment: Estoy más que seguro que debería ser `IF @fecha_grabacion_nula IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Tienen razón, no me fijé en esa condición. Sin embargo, mantengo mi postura acerca de GOTO. El que no exista en otros lenguajes no significa que no venga de esos tiempos.

Comment: o sea, que su error es simplemente el primer if, mas alla de todos los otros cambios que le pedis que haga? y existe en muchos... pero igual, no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con codigo spaghetti... nada...

Comment: Los cambios adicionales que sugiero son para facilitar la lectura del código y optimizar el rendimiento. El uso de GOTO es una mala práctica de desarrollo. https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-goto-statement-in-C-advised-to-avoid

Comment: @LuisCazares Parto señalando que para mi, la persona que responde tiene el justo derecho de emitir (dentro de lo sano) opiniones en su publicación. Pero el link que has puesto habla de otro lenguaje, te aconsejo buscar una publicación que hable de SQL (y de una fuente "más seria")

Comment: El link es la fuente de un sitio especializado en SQL https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-code-smells-rules/category-code/#APX1095 . También puedes tomar de referencia las reglas de Sonar que se dedican al análisis de código https://rules.sonarsource.com/tsql/RSPEC-907/ . Si quieres fuentes aun más serias, puedes tomar los dichos de Niklaus Wirth o Edsger W. Dijkstra que generaron la frase "La instrucción goto considerada dañina".

Comment: Siento que quizas mal entendiste mi comentario anterior. Ni siquiera era una critica

Comment: de tu link "The excessive GOTO use considered as poor programming practice that may lead to unmaintainable and unreadable code when the code grows long." el uso excesivo ;) y lo pone en potencial. De paso en la publicacion de Quora (una fuente muy poco confiable) los comentarios son mixtos... entre si y no...